# Meteor - Validating new user document serverside

Tags: meteor

I'm having trouble with this seemingly trivial stuff, harrrr!
I have this user document:

```
userData = {
  account: {
    type: 'free'
  },
  profile: {
    name: 'Artem',
  },
  username: 'aaa@gmail.com',
  password: '123'
};
```

Which I'm sending client-side: `Accounts.createUser(userData);`
Then server side I want to check if account type equals 'free'. If it doesn't - I want to abort new user creation (and hopefully throw error client side)
There are 2 functions which I've found in the docs that presumably can help me do it:

- [Accounts.validateNewUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validatenewuser)
  Problem: it receives 'trimmed-down' user object which doesn't contain properties other than `profile, username, password, email`. Thus I cannot validate `account.type` as it doesn't exist on user object being validated.
- [Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)
  Problem: it is called after a generic user object is created and there is no way I can cancel inserting new document in Users collection. It absolutely requires to return a user document. If I return `undefined` it throws errors on server:
  `Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error: insert requires an argument`
  It also doesn't allow to throw method errors (as it's not a method) -> thus I cannot log error client side.

Comment: How about you send the account type data as part of the profile object? Then you will be able to access this value in `Accounts.validateNewUser` and do your validation.

Comment: It's strange that you have to do those kind of tricks. I've filed an issue  - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6231

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Accounts.validateNewUser` with little change to your data structure:

```
userData = {
  profile: {
    name: 'Artem',
    account : {
       type : 'free'
    }
  },
  username: 'aaa@gmail.com',
  password: '123'
};
```

Then you should be able to access data you need.
As far as I remember there were some discussion on meteor forum about removing `profile` field, that's why I'm solving this kind of problems in different way. For me `Meteor.users` is collection which should not be changed for sake of peace in mind - it could be changed by future version of meteor. My approach require to write more code in the beginning, but later it pays off, because you have place to store data about user and `Meteor.users` collection has docs with minimal amount of data.

I would use [jagi:astronomy@0.12.1](http://astronomy.jagi.io/what-is-astronomy) to create schema and custom methods. In general I would create new collection `UserAccounts` with schema:

```
UserAccount = new Astro.Class( {
    name: 'UserAccount',
    collection: 'UserAccounts',
    fields: {
       'userId'            : {type: 'string'},
       'type'              : {type: 'string', default:'free'}
    },
} )
```

and add schema to `Meteor.users` :

```
User = new Astro.Class( {
    name: 'User',
    collection: Meteor.users,
    fields: {
       'services'            : {type: 'object'},
       'emails'              : {type: 'array'}
    },
    methods:{
        account : function(){
            return UserAccounts.findOne({userId:this._id})
        }
    }
} )
```

The usage looks like this:

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne();
user.account().type
```

In summary:

- Accounts.onCreateUser : always allow to create user account and always create `UserAccount` which corresponds to it ( with field `userId`)